# Are these functions orthonormal?

Tags: orthonormal, eigenfunctions

Are the following set of functions orthonormal over the interval $0$ to $1$?
$$Y_r(x) = \sin{\beta_r x}-\sinh{\beta_r x}-\frac{\sin\beta_r-\sinh\beta_r}{\cos\beta_r-\cosh\beta}\left(\cos\beta_r x-\cosh\beta_r x\right)$$
where $\beta_r$ are the positive solutions to:
$$1-\cos\beta_r\cosh\beta_r=0$$
I know that the functions $Y_r(x)$ are orthogonal. I went to check if they were orthonormal by evaluating $\int_0^1 Y_r Y_r \, dx$ numerical and checking if the integral equaled to $1$. For $\beta_r = 4.7300$ I get that the integral is equal to $1.03593$. For Larger values of $\beta_r$ the integral approaches $1$ so that makes me think that the set of functions is orthonormal and I am just encountering numerical error. Any thoughts?

Comment: If all the values computed, including the $\beta_r$, are done using Mathematica or similar software, then all the computations should be correct to nearly ten decimal places.

Comment: I did the integration using Matlab's symbolic integration tool. It's the behavior of $\cosh{\beta_r x}$ that leads me to believe the integration could be inaccurate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with your computations; these functions are not normalized.  In fact, Mathematica is able to compute the *exact* value of of the the squared norm of the first function to be

$$\int_0^1 Y_1^2(1,x) = \frac{(\sin (\beta_1 )-\sinh (\beta_1 ))^2}{(\cos (\beta_1 )-\cosh (\beta_1))^2}.$$

Since $\beta_1 \approx 4.73$, we get about $1.0359$ for the integral.

I assume this computation is coming out of a Sturm-Liouville problem and I don't find this type of behavior to be at all unusual in that context.

Comment: Hi @mark-mcclure. Thanks! The functions are the eigenfunctions to the eigenvalue problem associated with an Euler-Bernoulli doubly clamped beam (bridge). The modal equation is $\frac{d^4 Y}{dx^4}-\beta Y = 0$ with the boundary conditions: $Y(0) = 0$, $\frac{d Y(1)}{dx}=0$, $Y(1) = 0$ and $\frac{d Y(1)}{dx}=0$. It is interesting that for a singly clamped beam, i.e. the boundary conditions at $x=1$ are $\frac{d^2 Y(1)}{dx^2}=0$ and $\frac{d Y(1)^3}{d x^3} = 0$, no normalization is required. Thanks again for answering my question!

Comment: @MarkMcClure I noticed that you wrote in this answer, and on your site "Liou**S**ville" problem. Is it just a typo, or there is a reason to spell this name as you're doing?

Comment: @Artem It's certainly a typo. Thanks.

Comment: @John No problem - hope it helps.  You really have *four* boundary conditions?

Comment: @MarkMcClure there are four boundary conditions. The physical interpretation of the boundary conditions is the displacement and the slope of the displacement is zero at the boundaries. The equation in my previous comment is the modal equation to: $ \frac{EI}{L^4}\frac{\partial^4 Y(x,t)}{\partial x^4}-m\frac{\partial^2 Y(x,t)}{\partial t^2} = 0$ and I assumed  a solution of the form $Y = Y(x)\times C \cos(\omega t -\phi)$ and $\beta = \frac{m \omega L^4}{EI}$. If you have any insight I that I missed I really appreciate for you to share your knowledge as I only have my minor in mathematics.